# Debugger Options in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

[image]

I'm trying to understand the intended usage & purpose of various Debugger Options in Visual Studio 2013

**Local Windows Debugger** is understandable and works the same as in previous versions of Visual Studio,

**What are Remote Windows, Web Browser & Web Service Debuggers used for?**

Comment: Much like the Microsoft debugger team, I also have to give up trying to guess what kind of project you are trying to debug.

Comment: It is a C++/CLI project. I'm still wondering particularly what does the Web Browser Debugger & Web Service Debugger serve here.

Answer (score 1):

Remote Windows Debugger is used for debugging your project on a different machine (remote debugging - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2.aspx)

Web Browser Debugger is used for debugging web applications (asp.net) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165008.aspx

Web Service Debugger is used for debugging apps that contain Web Services

Comment: Thanks for explanation Maria Ghiondea. I'm still a bit confused. I've a C++/CLI project opened above. Does that mean Asp.Net could be used with C++. And that is Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop. Why is Asp.net debugger given as an option if this version of visual studio is not meant for web applications?

Comment: I wasn't aware of your SKU or app. This looks like an issue, I'll look into it and let you know! Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Just an update Abdullah - this looks like a C++ project system and I've routed it from the VS Debugger (which is my team) to their team. I'll keep you updated on the investigation. Thanks for pointing this out to us!

Comment: Thanks for the update, would definitely look forward to know more about it.